# How can I create toc with same format of pagenumbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a problem with creating the table of content of my book.
I would like to add a round bracket to the page number on some pages.
However, when I create the table of content, the TOC has only a page number without the round bracket.

This is my sample code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
% Layout packages
\RequirePackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}                                                                                                          
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\setpageWithbracket}{%
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \lhead{} \chead{(\thepage)} \rhead{} 
    \lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{}
    %\fancyhead[CE,CO]{(\thepage)} % option for twoside
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}%

\newcommand{\setnormalPage}{%
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \lhead{} \chead{\thepage} \rhead{} 
    \lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}%

\begin{document}
\setpageWithbracket 
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\newpage
\setnormalPage
\section{Introduction}
   
This is the first section.
      
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
       
\newpage


\section{Second Section}
       
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

This is my expected output.

[image]

I am so sorry for my English.
Please kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your page styles are very similar, except for the parentheses around `\thepage`, I suggest setting only one page style, and redefine the way the page number is set - adding the parentheses for the ToC and unnumbered section, and resetting it for the remainder of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
% Layout packages
\RequirePackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}

% Use a single page style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\lhead{} \chead{\thepage} \rhead{}
\lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{(\arabic{page})}% Put page numbers in parentheses
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}% Reset page number and set it without parentheses

\section{Introduction}
   
This is the first section.
      
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
       
\clearpage

\section{Second Section}
       
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Werner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the result of the `\thepage` macro.

```
% pagenumprob.tex  SE 593029
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
% Layout packages
\RequirePackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}

%%% change the page number appearance
\let\savethepage\thepage
\newcommand{\parenpage}{\renewcommand{\thepage}{(\savethepage)}}
\newcommand{\noparenpage}{\renewcommand{\thepage}{\savethepage}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{} \chead{\thepage} \rhead{}
\lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{}

\begin{document}

\parenpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\newpage
\noparenpage
\section{Introduction}
   
This is the first section.
      
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...
       
\newpage
\section{Second Section}
       
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\newpage 
\parenpage
\section{Third}

\newpage
\noparenpage
\section{Fourth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Perter Willson.